# How to enter the doubles quotes in string

Tags: c#, json, string, double-quotes

I have piece of code where I am trying to enter the double quotes, My code is as follow,

```
resulted_value = "{series_name : \"" + final_resulted_series_name + "\",period_name: \"" + period_name + "\",period_final_value: \"" + period_final_value + "\"}";
```

here in result \ is shown every-time, I have used "\"+variable+\"" and also @"""variable""" but I am not getting desired output..any help will be greatly appreciated.

------------------------EDIT 1--------------------
am getting following output

```
["{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\",period_final_value:17\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:17\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\",period_final_value:15\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:15\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\",period_final_value:13\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:13\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\",period_final_value:14.103\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:14.103\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\",period_final_value:14.404499999999999\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:14.404499999999999\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\",period_final_value:14.966999999999999\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:14.966999999999999\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\",period_final_value:15.67\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:15.67\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\",period_final_value:16.005\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:16.005\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\",period_final_value:16.63\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:16.63\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Alarm\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\",period_final_value:17\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Alarm\\\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:17\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Alarm\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\",period_final_value:15\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Alarm\\\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:15\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Alarm\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\",period_final_value:13\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Alarm\\\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:13\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Alarm\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\",period_final_value:14.103\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Alarm\\\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:14.103\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Alarm\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\",period_final_value:14.404499999999999\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Alarm\\\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:14.404499999999999\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Alarm\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\",period_final_value:14.966999999999999\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Alarm\\\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:14.966999999999999\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Alarm\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\",period_final_value:15.67\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Alarm\\\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:15.67\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Alarm\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\",period_final_value:16.005\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Alarm\\\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:16.005\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Alarm\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\",period_final_value:16.63\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Alarm\\\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:16.63\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Target\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\",period_final_value:17\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Target\\\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:17\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Target\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\",period_final_value:15\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Target\\\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:15\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Target\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\",period_final_value:13\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Target\\\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:13\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Target\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\",period_final_value:14.103\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Target\\\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:14.103\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Target\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\",period_final_value:14.404499999999999\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Target\\\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:14.404499999999999\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Target\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\",period_final_value:14.966999999999999\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Target\\\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:14.966999999999999\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Target\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\",period_final_value:15.67\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Target\\\",period_name:Q1 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:15.67\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Target\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\",period_final_value:16.005\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Target\\\",period_name:Q2 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:16.005\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Target\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\",period_final_value:16.63\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Target\\\",period_name:Q3 / 2013\\\",period_final_value:16.63\\\"}\""]
```

and I want to eliminate the \ and want every value inside "" so that it can be read and used in further code.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: `\"` is the correct way to escape the double quotation marks. Could you please post the output you are getting as well as your desired output?

Comment: How are you checking the output? If you're looking in the `Watch` or `Locals` window in the debugger, you are *supposed* to see the slashes.

Comment: The output string looks fine, run it through a validator: http://jsonlint.com/. Are you viewing the string in the debugger? As I said in my answer, write the string to a console window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can *recommend* to build this, if you are unsure, is with a serializer. For example:

```
var obj = new {
    series_name = final_resulted_series_name,
    period_name,
    period_final_value 
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

which produces (for values `abc`, `def` and `ghi` respectively):

```
{"series_name":"abc","period_name":"def","period_final_value":"ghi"}
```

If you are using concatenation, then *it will eventually bite you*. You need to know all the encoding rules, edge-cases and corner-cases to do this manually.

Comment: but this is applicable to return only one string at a time. whereas I have an array of string from which I want to eliminate the backslash from string.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @PrasadSS none of which relates to the question you asked. I suggest something radical: *ask the question that you want answered*....

Answer (score 1):

Write the output to a console window, the quotes are escaped fine. You're probably viewing in the debugger which will conserve the `\` slashes.

```
string final_resulted_series_name = "foo";
string period_name = "bar";
string period_final_value = "foobar";
string resulted_value = "{series_name : \"" + final_resulted_series_name + "\",period_name: \"" + period_name + "\",period_final_value: \"" + period_final_value + "\"}";

Console.Write(resulted_value);
```

Gives:

> {series_name : "foo", period_name: "bar", period_final_value: "foobar"}

This probably isn't the best way to construct a json string as Marc kindly points out. I would recommend using a json serializer.

If you're using [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) you can use the `jsonConvert` method:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

If not, you can use the following:

```
public virtual string ToJson()
{
    string json = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(this.GetType());
        ser.WriteObject(ms, this);
        json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }

    return json;
}
```

You should mark your object as using a `DataContract` and being `Serializable` to use this.

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
```

Comment: I would question whether concatenation is good advice unless you *know for certain* that the values can never contain any characters that would require escaping.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("You can use \"slashes\" to escape \" double quotes\"");
Console.WriteLine(@"Or use ""@"" before the string and double ""double quotes""");
```

Output:

> You can use "slashes" to escape " double quotes"
>
> Or use "@" before the string and double "double quotes"

Bear in mind that if you are inspecting the string in the debugger, you will still see the string as they appear in code (I.E. including escaping slashes, or double double quotes).