# To format the string to convert it into JSON format

Tags: c#, regex, json, string

I have written a code to eliminate the double quotes which is as follows,

```
resulted_value = "{series_name : \"" + final_resulted_series_name + "\",period_name: \"" + period_name + "\",period_final_value: \"" + period_final_value + "\"}";
```

Also tried with @"""variable""" but was futile, I want to eliminate the \ slash and want my every value to be inside "". Below is my obtained result.

```
["{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name: \"Q1 / 2013\",period_final_value: \"17\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name: \\\"Q1 / 2013\\\",period_final_value: \\\"17\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name: \"Q2 / 2013\",period_final_value: \"15\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name: \\\"Q2 / 2013\\\",period_final_value: \\\"15\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name: \"Q3 / 2013\",period_final_value: \"13\"}","\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name: \\\"Q3 / 2013\\\",period_final_value: \\\"13\\\"}\"","{series_name : \"Actual\",period_name: \"Q1 / 2013\",period_final_value: \"14.103\"}""]
```

Below is the code that I write to serialize the string value into JSON format.

```
modified_listofstrings.Add(resulted_value);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Json\Json.json", jSearializer.Serialize(resulted_value));
```

also I tried this method as well

```
var obj = new
      {
        series_name = final_resulted_series_name,
        period_name,
        period_final_value
      };
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Json\Json.json",jSearializer.Serialize(obj));
```

this eliminate backslash but only from first values and the output obtained is

```
[{"series_name":"Actual","period_name":"Q1 / 2013","period_final_value":"17"},"\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name: \\\"Q1 / 2013\\\",period_final_value: \\\"17\\\"}\"",{"series_name":"Actual","period_name":"Q2 / 2013","period_final_value":"15"},"\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name: \\\"Q2 / 2013\\\",period_final_value: \\\"15\\\"}\"",{"series_name":"Actual","period_name":"Q3 / 2013","period_final_value":"13"},"\"{series_name : \\\"Actual\\\",period_name: \\\"Q3 / 2013\\\",period_final_value: \\\"13\\\"}\""]
```

I want to eliminate backslash from all the values.

Below is the code which gives me the output,

```
if (xmlAttributeCollection_for_period != null)
                   {
                       var periodid = xmlAttributeCollection_for_period["periodid"];
                       xmlActions[j] = periodid.Value;
                       period_final_id = periodid.Value;
                       string period_name = Client.GetAttributeAsString(sessionId, periodid.Value, "name", "");

                       var action = xmlAttributeCollection_for_period["value"];
                       xmlActionsone[j] = action.Value;
                       period_final_value = action.Value;

                       values += final_resulted_series_name + ":" + period_name + ":" + period_final_value + ",";
                       string vals = values.Split(',')[1];
                       counts = values;
                       string[] periods = counts.Split(',');
                       Period1 = periods[j];
                       // string final_resulted_period_name = Client.GetAttributeAsString(sessionId, resulted_series_id, "name", "");
                       var obj = new
                       {
                           series_name = final_resulted_series_name,
                           period_name,
                           period_final_value
                       };

                       resulted_value = "{series_name : \"" + final_resulted_series_name + "\",period_name: \"" + period_name + "\",period_final_value: \"" + period_final_value + "\"}";
                       modified_listofstrings.Add(resulted_value);
                       System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Json\Json.json", jSearializer.Serialize(resulted_value));
                   }
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enter the doubles quotes in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927779/how-to-enter-the-doubles-quotes-in-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed the obj variable to list as follows

```
modified_listofstrings.Add(obj);
```

and then serialized the list as below

```
jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings)
```

declaration were as below,

```
 List<object> modified_listofstrings = new List<object>();
 System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer =
             new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
```

and it gave the desired output